# Scheduling minimization Integer Programming problem formulation

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming

I am working with Integer Optimization optimization. I have a problem with **t** tasks and every task **i** needs **w_i** weeks to be completed and **p_i_t** workers on that specific week. There is a total time in weeks to complete all tasks. I need to optimize (min) the max value of workers needed in any week (variables to define: starting week for every particular task, or similar). Weeks needed per task and amount of worker in each week are given as data points.

There is also a constraint: once a task starts, it should be finished (can't be paused). All tasks could run in parallel if needed.

How can I model this optimization problem formally?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to [or.stackexchange.com](https://or.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes. I didn't realize it. Sorry for that, I'm moving it now.